# Explanation of this C++ code I learned in college

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie here and I just started college. We are learning **C++** and I find it a little bit difficult, because of the way the teachers explain. 
Yesterday we did a task that says to create a program, which finds **greatest common divisor** **of 2 numbers**. So, the teacher started writing the code, but the explanation wasn't enough for me and I really need some help right now.
(I putted comments on the things I don't understand.)
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a, b;
    cout << "a = ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "b = ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "GCD (" << a << ", " << b << ") is ";

    if (a != 0 && b != 0){
        size_t min = abs(a) < abs(b) ? abs(a) : abs(b); //What's that after (?)?
        size_t max = abs(a) > abs(b) ? abs(a) : abs(b);
        size_t diff = max - min; //What is that variable used for?

        while (diff > 0)
        {
            min = diff < min ? diff : min;
            max = diff > min ? diff : min;
            diff = max - min;
        }
        cout << min << endl;
    }
    else{
        if (a != 0 || b != 0)
            cout << (a>b ? a : b) << endl;
        else
            cout << "not possible!!!\n";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

*QUESTION:* When should I put {} on if's, while's etc.?

Comment: "When should I put {} on if's, while's etc.?" - always.

Comment: 1) What book are you using to learn C++ from, alongside the lectures? If you aren't using any, consider picking one from [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). 2) What, exactly, you find unclear about the explanations given to you? What were those explanations? If you don't give such information to us, we might just repeat what your lecturer already said, which would help no-one.

Comment: The first commented expression is called the  'conditional operator'.  "Expression1 ? Expression2 : Expression3"

Comment: tbh i think the best you can do is ask your prof or co-students. Working together with others and direct tutoring is extremely important and valuable and cannot be replaced by online Q&As

Comment: The correct person to ask is your teacher. If they don't realise they are assuming students know certain language constructs, they won't adjust their approach to teaching the course.

Comment: ...moreover we cannot know what was your teachers intention when presenting you this code. If they didnt get the message across you should let them know. However, all that is of course not a reason to not ask questions here ;)

Comment: Beware that this code shows a lot of bad habits. My impression is that your teacher may be bad at what they teach...

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux For that matter, it's a terrible implementation of the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux i would say it depends. eg. if the lesson was about using the ternary then the code has something, if the lesson was about using standard functions when applicable then the code is a fail ;)

Comment: @Damien It is equivalent to the Euclidean algorithm; it just uses repeated subtraction in place of division. Division _is_ repeated subtraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax for an `if-statement`

```
if ( condition ) statement-true else statement-false
```

`statement-true` is either one statement or a block of statements in `{...}`

So you can use `if` without `{...}` if there is only one line. But it is better to always use `{...}`.

Comment: "_is either one statement or a block of statements in `{...}`_" Technically speaking, it is always a single statement. It's just `{...}` is a compound statement.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary when you need more that one line/statement to be executed by the if/else/while. Valid examples:

```
if (a != 0 || b != 0)
    cout << (a>b ? a : b) << endl;

if (a != 0 || b != 0) cout << (a>b ? a : b) << endl;

if (a != 0 || b != 0) {
    cout << (a>b ? a : b) << endl;
    a++; }
```

If you did:

```
if (a != 0 || b != 0) 
    cout << (a>b ? a : b) << endl;
    a++;
```

The the `a++;` would be executed regardless of the `if` condition.

Some programmers like to use `{}` even for single statements because they believe it leads to more usable and maintainable code. I do not belong to that group but I can see the arguments on either side.

Answer (score 1):

```
size_t min = abs(a) < abs(b) ? abs(a) : abs(b); //What's that after (?)?
```

C and C++ have a construct that is similar to an `if`-`else` statement. This line basically says that if `abs(a)` is smaller than `abs(b)`, then `min` should take the value of `abs(a)`; otherwise, it should take the value of `abs(b)`.

```
size_t diff = max - min; //What is that variable used for?
```

It's not clear what you mean here. If you mean `diff`, the code essentially uses it in the subsequent `while` loop to perform division by repeated subtraction. This is a very strange thing to do, especially because it is so inefficient, and division would have been more  compact and efficient in the loop. It's even stranger given that earlier the author uses `?:` (which you asked about); that construction is used mainly because it's more compact and efficient than an `if`-`else` statement, but this is rather strange code, anyway.

> When should I put {} on if's, while's etc.?

You should do it by default. You don't *have* to do it if only one statement is to be performed when the condition is true (resp. false) but people usually do as a matter of good style and to assist readability. For instance, this code

```
if (a != 0 || b != 0)
    cout << (a>b ? a : b) << endl;
else
    cout << "not possible!!!\n";
```

could just as easily be

```
if (a != 0 || b != 0) {
    cout << (a>b ? a : b) << endl;
} else {
    cout << "not possible!!!\n";
}
```

...and a lot of instructors would actually *require* the latter from learners.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers:

> ```
> //What's that after (?)?
> ```

```
foo ? bar : qux;
```

Is the use of the ternary operator.

If `foo` is true the expression evaluates to `bar` else it evaluates to `qux`.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my two cents...

This

```
if (a != 0 || b != 0)
        cout << (a>b ? a : b) << endl;
```

is equivalent to

```
if (a != 0 || b != 0) {
        cout << (a>b ? a : b) << endl;
}
```

The big difference comes when you realize that code is not something static that you write once and then never change again. Lets change the example a little bit (intentially weird intendation)

```
if ( x )           // (I)
    y = a;
    z = b;
```

is **not** the same as

```
if ( x ) {         // (II)
    y = a;
    z = b;
}
```

Using brackets allows you to focus on only the part you care about. Consider that you later decide to swap the two lines, then

```
if ( x ) {
    z = b;
    y = a;
}
```

is still ok (its the same as (II), apart from swapping the two instructions), while

```
if ( x )
    z = b;
    y = a;
```

is doing something completely different as the version above (I). If you use the brackets you dont need to care whether those two lines are inside a if block. To decide if you can swap them you need to look at nothing more than those two lines. This is not the case if you do not use the brackets. This may seem like a minor thing, though I have seen countless bugs caused by not putting brackets where there could be some.

Answer (score 0):

***For 1 line of code following `if`, `else`, `else if`, `while`, etc***

```
if (<some condition>)
    //1 line of code`
```

and

```
if (<some condition>)
{
   //1 line of code
}
```

...are equivalent and it is up to you (personal style,developer choice,readability etc.) to make that decision.

***For > 1 line of code following `if, else, else if, while, etc`***
`{}` is required if you want code completely scoped to the condition statement. It is up to you the developer to make sure to scope these lines of code (i.e. the compiler will not warn you about this.. it will not know if the intent was 1 line or multiple lines).

So an example

```
if(<some condition>)
{
    //line of code 1
    //line of code 2
}
```

the compiler will let you do this...

```
if(<some condition>)
    // line of code 1
    // line of code 2
```

but `//line of code 2` has no relation to the `if` condition since it was not scoped with `{}` and will be executed regardless of the `if` statement condition.